# Windows azure web application script recording using jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I tried to record below screen using jmeter script recorder. But after executing the recorded script, I'm getting blue screen as html response without showing any screen content.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAvQ7.jpg)

Is that possible to record windows azure applications using jmeter. If yes please let me know what are the steps I need to flow to capture above screen

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use Blazemeter. You will have to create new account and simply record your steps. You can directly create jmx files out of that and then can edit from jmeter accordingly.